# RuntimeError: Postgis Plugin: authentication method 10 not supported

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to render a mapnik file but encountering the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/siphi/PycharmProjects/test2/kmgmap.py", line 29, in <module>
    roads_ds = mapnik.PostGIS(host='localhost', user='postgres', password='', dbname='kmg3', table='planet_osm_line')
  File "C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\python\2.7\site-packages\mapnik\__init__.py", line 430, in PostGIS
    return CreateDatasource(keywords)
RuntimeError: Postgis Plugin: authentication method 10 not supported
```

Connection string: `'host=localhost dbname=kmg3 user=postgres connect_timeout=4'`

I've tried downgrading to `md5` from `scram-sha-256` authentication, but I still get the same error message.

I tried the following steps from a previous post:

- change `password_encryption` to `md5` in file `postgresql.conf`
- change the first 3 occurrences of `scram-sha-256` to `trust` in file `pg_hba.conf`

  ```
  # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
  local   all             all                                     trust
  # IPv4 local connections:
  host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
  # IPv6 local connections:
  host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
  ```
- restart the `postgresql` service
- execute `psql -U postgres` (you won't be asked for a password)
- change the password with the command `\password username`
- change the first 3 occurrences of `trust` to `md5` in file `pg_hba.conf`

  ```
  # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
  local   all             all                                     md5
  # IPv4 local connections:
  host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
  # IPv6 local connections:
  host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
  ```
- restart the `postgresql` service

But I'm still getting the same error. I'm not interested in upgrading the PostgreSQL client software at this stage. I'd just like to downgrade the password encryption.

Comment: That should work.  Maybe the config files you edited were not the right ones.  Like, for a different database server than the one you are using, or unused backups, or dummy example files.  Intentionally introduce a syntax error into the config files and restart the database.  If it starts, then those are not the right files.

Comment: I have little sympathy for people who insist in running dangerously outdated old software.